# MacOS - automake: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, automake

I am trying to install `automake` on MacOS using `brew`. From terminal I write, `brew install automake` says `Warning: automake-1.15 already installed`.
When I then try `automake version` it responds `-bash: automake: command not found`. I am using OS X El Capitan.

```
$ automake version
-bash: automake: command not found
$ brew install automake
Warning: automake-1.15 already installed
$ automake version
-bash: automake: command not found
```

Comment: Is `automake` linked? `brew link automake` will warn you if it already is linked, and make the links if not. If that doesn't work confirm that it is in your PATH.

Comment: You might also be looking for the flag `--version`.

Comment: its work... `unlink` it and then `link` again working :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution had to do with `brew` having failed to link the binary into the `PATH`. Un-linking and re-linking solved it.

Answer (score 1):

What an infuriating problem! In a Docker situation,

It is so hard to get autoconf 1.15 working that we had to get the aid of a Grand Ultra Master Expert to investigate the issue and get it working on Mac.  It then worked beautifully.

Later I happened to upgrade a Mac to High Sierra, it stopped working! **Even though autoconf 1.15 working fine.**

How to fix:

**Short answer, I simply trashed the local repo, for goodness sake, and checked out the repo again.**

It then worked fine!

It has something to do with the aclocal.m4 and similar files.  I endlessly massaged them but nothing.  Someone suggsted just scratching the repo and getting it again: everything then worked!