# julius: command not found even though it is installed

Tags: speech-recognition, julius-speech

I am working with speech processing and needed to install `julius`. I executed the following command on my Mac:

```
brew install julius
```

This installed julius-4.3.1. However, when I type julius, I get:

```
-bash: julius: command not found
```

So I tried re-installing julius, but recieved this message:

```
Warning: julius-4.3.1 already installed
```

Even `julius-4.3.1` is not a recognised command. So How do I install julius on a mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOS - automake: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41024838/macos-automake-command-not-found)

Comment: It happens that brew doesn't properly update the PATH, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use `julius.dSYM` instead of `julius`